# Get MIN value from array without 0

Tags: php

```
$array1 = array(0,1,3,0);
$array2 = array(2,0,3,2);
$array3 = array(0,4,5,1);

echo min($array1) . "\n";
echo min($array2) . "\n";
echo min($array3) . "\n";
```

this return me:

```
0
0
0
```

but i want receive:

```
1
2
1
```

How to skip 0 in function MIN?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE will be removed.

so it will remove `0` for you.

```
echo min(array_filter($array1)) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to `array_filter`, you can be more explicit with

```
$min = min(array_diff($array1, array(0));    // result = 1
```

This can let you disregard more values very easily, e.g.

```
$min = min(array_diff($array1, array(0, 1)); // result = 3
```